# Callback URL - Social Logins

Tags: wordpress, facebook, url, twitter, callback

Can someone explain what the Callback URL is and what exactly it's used for?
I'm setting up Social login for my WordPress website and in Facebook and Twitter it asks for a callback URL.
At the moment i have left these blank and it works fine but was wondering what exactly are they used for?

I've read on other websites that it should be set like this:

```
http://mywebsite.com/user/facebook/login
```

But I don't understand what to use it for.
Is it to redirect the user to your site after they login via their social accounts? If that's the case, doesn't it do that without a callback URL?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Is it to redirect the user to your site after they login via their social accounts?

Yes.

> If that's the case, doesn't it do that without a callback URL?

How would it know *where* to redirect back to, if that information wasn’t passed to it in the first place?

The callback URL is passed as a parameter in the login dialog call. That allows the login provider to a) redirect back to the app, and b) check if the app is even allowed to perform login under that URL.

Comment: Thanks for that information!
What URL address will need to be put in there to redirect the user back from where they came from?

For example, if there many different pages with a register option, how to redirect user back to that specific page?

Comment: All callback URLs your app uses have to be registered with Facebook in the app settings, so you can’t really have them “dynamic.” Would be easier to store the address of the page login was triggered on into the session, use one non-static callback URL, and when the user is redirected back there from Facebook, then redirect them again to the URL they were on originally.